# How to Display Google Drive files in ListView?

Tags: android, listview

This is what i am trying to do.But getting error.When i initialized string array.. "hi" "Hello" only these two are coming in listview. But in the loop when i try to Assign file Title to String array getting error. Details given below.

```
     Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
     {
        @Override
            public void run()
            {
                showToast("Cal");
                monthsArray=GetFiles(service);  // Line No 52
            }

     });
     thread.start();

            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,                  monthsArray);     
             lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);



                public String[] GetFiles(Drive service)
                {
                  ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
                  String[] nm = null;

                 try {
                   String req= service.files().list().getFields();
                  Files.List request = service.files().list().setQ("mimeType !=     'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'");
                 FileList files = request.execute();
                 for(File file : files.getItems())
              { 
                String field= file.getId();
                String title = file.getTitle();
                nm[i]=title;     //Line No 80;
                MyFiles.add(title); 
              }     
           } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
                 showToast("sending back.."); 
               return nm;
             }


             Error Details:  Line No 80 and 52

             LogCat
              FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10881
              java.lang.NullPointerException
              at com.example.vturesources.pdf.GetFiles(pdf.java:80)
              at com.example.vturesources.pdf$1.run(pdf.java:52)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: This was Happened because of thread. Solution is use arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in new thread to fill adapter after getting files from drive